# Visual studio security problems when running projects - Trust levels

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, full-trust

I had been working fine on my previous machine, but i bought a new one and I installed everything I needed there (Win 7 x64 Enterprise, VS 2010 Proffesional SP1) and I downloaded several projects from my CVSNT repository.

Now, in the new PC,  I'm having a lot of security troubles running the applications. The last one says something like

> Attempt by security transparent method 'Namespace.class.method()' to
>   access security critical method 'Namespace.class.method()' failed.
>
> Assembly 'Assembly' is marked with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security
>   transparency model. Level 2 transparency causes all methods in
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent
>   by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

Before that never happened before, and now several trust issues are bothering all the time.

I'm running VS as administrator and dont have the UAC enabled.

Any suggestion of how to solve this issues and why are all my projects having Trust problems?

Comment: A friend of mine did the same (format the pc and reinstalled everything) and everything works fine for him. The only difference is that mine is a laptop (lenovo) with OS from fabric and his is a desktop pc an we installed the OS from a generic disc (Not manufacturer specific)

Answer (score 2):

Is this the first time the project has been compiled or used with .Net 4.0? If so, there have been changes to the security model in .Net 4.0. where Microsoft has tried to simplify the Code Access Security (CAS) model. Desktop applications and other non-framework code now have some restrictions by default and those restrictions are enforced at runtime rather than compile time or assembly load time.

To fix it, you may need to add `[assembly:SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]` to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. See They are described in detail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103(v=VS.100).aspx for more info.

Comment: No, in my old computer it has already been compiled to framework 4, it was migrated from 3.5 to 4 but a long time ago.

Comment: Humor me. Have you tried adding the attribute suggested? If it fixes the problem, it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Akton, thanks for this solution, it fixed it for me :-)